# Can I CHANGE an Apache CustomLog configuration line from a file in conf.d?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

My Apache 2.2 `httpd.conf` file contains the following line:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

I want to instead use:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log "a different log format that I prefer"
```

But I can't make changes to `httpd.conf` directly: I make all config changes using files in the `conf.d/` directory.

Naturally, I've tried adding

```
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
```

to a file called `conf.d/logging.conf`, but this gets run **in addition to** the first one, resulting in 2 log lines per access! Is there a way to cancel the first, and only use my new one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you give the new long a new name, such as this:

```
CustomLog logs/access_combined_log combined
```

then you would have your log as you want it.